# How to use IFormFile as property when uploading file to a server using Asp.NET Core 3.1 framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.0

I am trying to create a Web API that would handle storing files.

Asp.Net core 1.0+ framework ships with [IFormFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-3.1) interface which allows binding the file to a view-model. The [documentation about uploading files in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/file-uploads?view=aspnetcore-3.1) states the following

> **IFormFile** can be used directly as an action method parameter or as a
>   bound model property.

When I used `IFormFile` as an action method's parameter, it worked with no issues. But in my case, I want to use it as a property on a model as I would like to bind other values in addition to include custom validation rules. Here is my view-model.

```
public class NewFile
{
    [Required]
    [MinFileSize(125), MaxFileSize(5 * 1024 * 1024)]
    [AllowedExtensions(new[] { ".jpg", ".png", ".gif", ".jpeg", ".tiff" })]
    public IFormFile File { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? CustomField1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? CustomField2 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int? CustomField3 { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my code for both the client request and the server code that accepts the file. Both methods are placed in the same controller for the sake of simplicty. But in reality, the "client" method will be placed into a separate application that sends over the files.

```
[ApiController, Route("api/[controller]")]
public class FilesController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("client")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Client()
    {
        using HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        // we need to send a request with multipart/form-data
        var multiForm = new MultipartFormDataContent
        {
            // add API method parameters
            { new StringContent("CustomField1"), "1" },
            { new StringContent("CustomField2"), "1234" },
            { new StringContent("CustomField3"), "5" },
        };

        // add file and directly upload it
        using FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenRead("C:/1.jpg");
        multiForm.Add(new StreamContent(fs), "file", "1.jpg");

        // send request to API
        var responce = await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:123/api/files/store", multiForm);

        return Content("Done");
    }

    [HttpPost("store")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Store(NewFile model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                var filename = MakeFileName(model, Path.GetFileName(model.File.FileName));

                Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(filename));

                using var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create);
                await model.File.CopyToAsync(stream);

                return PhysicalFile(filename, "application/octet-stream");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return Problem(e.Message);
            }
        }

        // Are there a better way to display validation errors when using Web API?
        var errors = string.Join("; ", ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(v => v.ErrorMessage));

        return Problem(errors);
    }
}
```

When I make the request, I get the following error yet the request never makes it to the `store` method as I placed a breakpoint there but it never makes it there.

> StatusCode: 415, ReasonPhrase: 'Unsupported Media Type', Version: 1.1,
>   Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent

How can I correctly send over the file to the server and have it bind to the `File` property on my view-model?

Comment: Use `[FromForm]` to bind model  `public async Task<IActionResult> Store([FromForm]NewFile model)`. `ApiController` by default expects JSON unless explicitly told otherwise

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ApiController` by default expects JSON unless explicitly told otherwise

Use [`[FromForm]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromformattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1) to bind model using form-data in the request body.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Store([FromForm]NewFile model) {
    //...
}.
```

Reference [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding)

> the CustomField1, CustomField2, and CustomField3` are null even though they are being sent along as you see in my original question

the client is not sending those other fields correctly. You have the content and field names switched

```
var multiForm = new MultipartFormDataContent {
    // add API method parameters
    { new StringContent("1"), "CustomField1" },
    { new StringContent("1234"), "CustomField2" },
    { new StringContent("5"), "CustomField3" },
};
```

Comment: I added `[FromForm]` as per your suggestion but still did not work. I removed `[ApiController]` attribute from the controller and the request made it to the `Store` method as expected. However, the `CustomField1`, CustomField2`, and `CustomField3` are null even though they are being sent along as you see in my original question.

Comment: @John the client is not sending those other fields correctly. You have the content and names switched

Comment: How do I test this type of API in postman or Fiddler? Can you please suggest.